# regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need to match Regular expression for

```
txt = "orderType not in ('connect', 'Modify', 'random', 'more')"
```

correct data:

```
txt = "orderType is in ('connect')"
txt = "orderType not in ('connect', 'Modify')"
```

N number of items can be inside bracket, with quotes and comma separated like above. Rest of all should not be matched, like below

```
txt = "orderType not in ('connect', Modify, 'ran=dom', 'more')" 
import re
pattern1 = '\w+\s+(?:is|not)\sin\s+\('
pattern2 = '\'\w+\''
pattern3 = '\s?,\s?'+pattern2+'+'
print(re.findall(pattern3, txt))
pattern6 = pattern1+pattern2
pattern5 = pattern1+pattern2+pattern3
pattern4 = (pattern2+ pattern3)  +'|'+ (pattern2 )
pattern = pattern5+ '|' + pattern6
print(re.findall(pattern,txt))
```

my output is `["orderType not in ('connect', 'Modify'"]`

expected output should: `orderType not in ('connect', 'Modify', 'random', 'more')`

Be it entire line, I won't mind if it returns true for all matched and false for the rest

Comment: Thank Wiktor, But that is not the major issue, I am more concerned about the data inside brackets, with your (?:is|not)

output changed to ["orderType not in ('connect', 'Modify'"]
but there are two more terms missing after modify

Comment: So, which rule is valid? A string that only contains `(...)` with 2 arguments in it?

Comment: it can take multiple arguments in it,  ('connect'), ('connect',''modify'),('connect',''modify','example') etc. N number of arguments

Comment: i don't think it is a job for regex. you have a list `('connect', 'Modify', 'random', 'more')` it will be easier to write and maintain if you avoid regex

Comment: I am not sure we can provide a valid regex answer here. What are the escaping rules here? How is `'` defined in those single quote string literals? ``\'``? Then see https://regex101.com/r/QwWpYW/2

Comment: Yes I am sure other way we can handle it easily, but I am sure we can work with Regex aswell :

**    subReg= '\w+\s?!?=\s?\‘\w+\’$'**

    subReg2 = ('\s+?(?:AND|OR)\s+?'+subReg)+".+"

    subReg3 = subReg+subReg2

    reg =  (subReg3)+'|' + (subReg) 

Using the above patterns, I was able to match all the below cases
orderType = 'Modify'
orderType = 'Modify' AND orderType = 'connect'
orderType = 'Modify' or orderType = 'connect' AND domain = 'random;
(orderType = 'Modify' or orderType = 'connect)' AND domain = 'random;

Comment: you're searching only letters, meaning your pattern will consider valid `'coninuct', 'connectolol', 'supercallifragillisticexpialidocious'` and so.

Comment: i am searching for alphanumberic.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some parentheses. When combining expressions `p1` and `p2` that each match a string `s1` and `s2` respectively, the regexp resulting from `p1+p2` will not necessarily match `s1+s2`, due to the order of precedence in the regexp syntax. The following will do what you likely wanted (the changes are for 'pattern3' and 'pattern'):

```
import re
pattern1 = '\w+\s+(?:is|not)\sin\s+\('
pattern2 = '\'\w+\''
pattern3 = '(?:\s?,\s?'+pattern2+')+'
print(re.findall(pattern3, txt))
pattern6 = pattern1+pattern2
pattern5 = pattern1+pattern2+pattern3
pattern = '(?:'+pattern5+ ')|(?:' + pattern6+')'
print(re.findall(pattern,txt))
```

I only added the needed () in the regexp string, no other fixes. Note this doesn't match the closing parenthesis of the input string - add `'\s+\)` at the end, if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import re

texts=[ "orderType not in ('connect', 'Modify', 'random', 'more')",
        "orderType is in ('connect')",
        "orderType not in ('connect', 'Modify')"
        ]

reg=re.compile( r"\s*orderType\s+(?:is|(not))\s+in\s+\(\s*'connect'\s*(?(1),\s*'Modify'\s*\)|\))" )
for txt in texts:
    m=reg.fullmatch(txt)
    print("matched -->" if m else "not matched -->",txt)

"""
Descriptions:
    (is|(not))      The external parentheses to encapsulate the '|' pattern (or);
    (?:is|(not))    ?: The encapsulated expression matching as a group, is not interesting to us as a whole.
    (not)           If matched, it will be the 1st group.
    \(              Escape sequence, it matches the '(' .
    (?(1),\s*'Modify'\s*\)|\)   Yes-no pattern (?(group_number)expr1|expr2)
"""
```